# What is the easiest way to get total number for lines of code (LOC) in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, database, t-sql, statistics

I need to provide statistics on how many lines of code `(LOC)` associated with a system. The application part is easy but I need to also include any code residing within the SQL Server database. This would apply to stored procedures, functions, triggers, etc.

How can I easily get that info? Can it be done (accurately) with **TSQL** by querying the system `tables\sprocs`, etc?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Management Studio, right click the database you want a line count for... select Tasks -> Generate Scripts,   you can select script options in the Scripts Wizard to include or exclude objects,   when you have it set the way you like it can generate to a new query window

Answer (score 2):

Just select all the text from syscomments and count how many lines you have. The text column is text, which you can't really see in Management studio, so I would write a program or power shell script like this:

```
$conn = new-object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection("Server=server;Database=database;Integrated Security=SSPI")
$cmd = new-object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand("select text from syscomments", $conn)
$conn.Open()
$reader = $cmd.ExecuteReader()

$reader.Read() | out-null
$reader.GetString(0) | clip
$reader.Close()
$conn.Close()
```

Paste into an editor that has a line count, and you're done.

Answer (score 1):

Personally you might just script the objects to file using SQL Server Management tools, it will get a few extras in there for the checks to do the drop first incase the object exists.